# optimization flag '-falign-functions' is not supported in armcc

Tags: arm, armcc

How to achieve a similar effect to -falign-functions of gcc flag in armcc.

I'm using armcc to compile my C program, I think some functions suffer from performance degradation due to addresses not being aligned to 16 bytes.

So I would like to force the function address to be aligned to 16 bytes to verify my guess, which is easy in GCC, but seems to be difficult for armcc.